# Send SIGINT to iTerm from vim

Tags: terminal, macvim, iterm2

I'm using [vim-rspec](https://github.com/thoughtbot/vim-rspec) on a mac with macvim and iterm. I'm using [this command](https://github.com/thoughtbot/vim-rspec/blob/2cf8c5002cb89eb8e9aabe59d25b89dc5afec88a/plugin/rspec.vim#L44) to clear the iTerm screen and run the test in iTerm.

```
let g:rspec_command = "clear && rspec {spec}"
let g:rspec_runner = "os_x_iterm"
```

I wanted to know what will be the command to interrupt the current process like with `Ctrl+c`. I've try `^\Quit && clear && rspec {spec}` but I get `zsh: substitution failed`.

Any ideas?

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, you would like to stop the `rspec` process from within Vim. Am I correct?

Comment: thanks @Carpetsmoker. My rspec test are run in the iTerm window it is a separate one from Macvim. I would like to stop rspec or any process that happen in the iTerm window. Maybe I can run a `kill 'rspec_process' && clear && rspec {spec}`

Comment: You can probably use `pkill` or `killall` to kill it: e.g. `:!pkill rspec`. This will kill all rspec processes, but this is probably not an issue. This should also close the terminal window, as the process running inside of it is now finished. You can then restart it by using `:call RunAllSpecs()` (or one of the other functions) again.

Comment: Thanks a lot Carpetsmoker. I found an answer and will publish what ?I've found

Comment: It's nearly work. I've try something like `let g:rspec_command = "pkill -f rerun && clear && rerun bin/rspec spec/services/user_management_service_spec.rb"` But the command is send to the terminal. If I do `:!pkill -f rerun` it kill properly the process without killing the window.

Comment: I moved this issue to the github issue of vim-rspec I will post the full answer when I will get it : https://github.com/thoughtbot/vim-rspec/issues/110